# html:text how to set placeholder attribute

Tags: java, html, jsp

I mostly do HTML/CSS/JS so i'm kind'a lost here, so no idea if this is possible the way i want it anyway, this is it:

I have this code

```
<html:text styleClass="span4" title="No spaces or dashes" />
```

I want this input to render with the attribute "placeholder".  How can i go about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I checked this ref but I didn't see anything: http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/html/textarea.html

Answer (score 4):

If struts doesn't provide then you could inject it using jQuery if you need it

```
$("#idOfInputText").attr('placeholder', 'some text')
```

you can supply id using `styleId` attribute of struts's tag

Comment: Thanks guys.  I knew this was possible but was hoping there was a cleaner way.  I guess this will have to do.  :(

Comment: @WootWoot Yes its not cleaner :)

Comment: At least you don't have to roll your own custom javascript. I think I'll use it.